# How to use $cookie in factory/service in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

In one of the app i am building, i want to use $cookie in service(.factory(...)).

When i use the $cookie i get $injector/module error. Can any one help me in this regard ?

Here is the code i have written.

```
app.factory("AuthenticationService", function($location,$cookies,setUserCreds) 
{

 return {

  login: function(credentials) {
    if (credentials.username == "MyName" || credentials.password == "admin") {
        $cookies.put("userName",credentials.username);          
        $location.path('/home');

   } 
}}});
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're doing the dependency injection correctly.  See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the example from the angular documentation:

```
myApp.factory('apiToken', ['clientId', function apiTokenFactory(clientId) {
  var encrypt = function(data1, data2) {
    // NSA-proof encryption algorithm:
    return (data1 + ':' + data2).toUpperCase();
  };

  var secret = window.localStorage.getItem('myApp.secret');
  var apiToken = encrypt(clientId, secret);

  return apiToken;
}]);
```

`'clientId'` is the name the module knows the service by and the parameter you pass the factory function is the name your factory will know it by. You only have the parameter.

Yours should look like this:

```
app.factory("AuthenticationService",['$location', '$cookies', 'setUserCreds', function($location, $cookies, setUserCreds) {
    ...
}]);
```

That $injector error usually amounts to *"What service are you talking about?"*

Comment: @freshtoUI Happy to help. I'm pretty new to Angular myself and do little things like this all the time. =)